# Javascript Promise with Fetch results in "undefined" in implementation of Stripe API

Tags: javascript, c#, promise, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement the Stripe payment API in my website. However, I'm not very familiar with JavaScript, which is leading to some issues.

Most of my code is taken from [Stripe's website](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#create-customer), with some modifications made to better suit my own site.

I have a function `CreateCustomer`, which is intended to create a customer based on input from a form:

```
        async function createCustomer () {
            var emailJSON = {
                "email": `${document.querySelector('#email-field').value}`
            };

             const output = await fetch('/create-customer', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(emailJSON)
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    return result;
                });

            return output;

        }
```

This function is called by another function, and the output is stored because I have another function which requires the customer's Id.

```
var handleForm = function () {

// other code

const customerPromise = createCustomer();
var customer = customerPromise.data;

// more code
}
```

The fetch call in `CreateCustomer` calls the following C# code:

```
  [Route ("create-customer")]
  [ApiController]
  public class CustomerCreationController : Controller
  {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CustomerCreateRequest request)
    {
      var customers = new CustomerService();
      var customer = customers.Create(new CustomerCreateOptions
      {
        Email = request.Email,
      });

      return Json(new { _customer = customer.Id });
    }

    public class CustomerCreateRequest
    {
      [JsonProperty("email")]
      public string? Email { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

From what I understand about Promises, if I call on the promise before it's resolved, I will get "undefined". But I also think I understand that if I await the promise (as I have done with the fetch in `CreateCustomer`), this shouldn't be an issue. However, whenever I run this code, I end up saving undefined in my `customer` variable in `handleForm`.

Like I said, I'm pretty unfamiliar with JavaScript, so the problem is probably some quirk of the language and/or Promises that I've overlooked. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your `createCustomer` is async, you need to await it, when calling it:

```
var handleForm = async function () {
  // other code

  const customerPromise = await createCustomer();
  var customer = customerPromise.data;

  // more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Marco is correct.

You also doing await and including .then witch is redundant.

Here are your options for promises:

```js
// Using async/await
async function createCustomer () {
  try {
    const requestBody = {
      email: `${document.querySelector('#email-field').value}`
    };

    const response = await fetch('/create-customer', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    })
    const data = await response.json()
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  
}

/*
If you are calling createCustomer somewhere it has to
either be a async function to allow await, or
use .then((data) => console.log(data))
*/
const data = await createCustomer();
```

```js
// Promise chains
async function createCustomer (callback) {
  const requestBody = {
    email: `${document.querySelector('#email-field').value}`
  };

  fetch('/create-customer', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => callback(data))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
}

createCustomer((data) => {
  // do something with data
})
```

One little thing with fetch is that you also have to await the .json() call. Since that is also a promise.
If you are doing a lot of network requests maybe take a look at [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).